# Visualforce error in Summer 16

Tags: visualforce, summer-16

During the past week(or two), our testers have logged quite a few bugs regarding VF errors. They are just standard ones:

> Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page

Now, when I try to reproduce it(with debug logs enabled of course), the flow of our app goes as it should and I can not get to this VF error page.

I also tried the same path with the user that was used when it happened, but still no success(if you can call normal behaviour a *no success* and an error a *success* of course).

The sandbox that was/is used is already on Summer 16. Was there any bug and a hotfix that was causing VF pages to fail? Or was it just a random occasion that we should try to reproduce by following this path gazillions of times?

In Spring 16 everything was working fine and there weren't any code changes to these pages/controllers.

Comment: Doesn't sound like the same issue but might be related to [Edit page throws "The link you followed wasn’t valid for your session..." if overridden with Visualforce page part of a managed package](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jknNQAQ). Also worth checking the "Development Mode" checkbox (might have to be an SA) on a User in the org that has the problem to get the stack trace.